# WEB API OData Optimistic Concurrency | Using ETag instead of TimeStamp

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, odata

## Context

To enable Optimistic Concurrency the following change was made to the Customer Data Model, using Entity Framework 6.

Before, without `TimeStamp`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After, with `TimeStamp`:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

## Results

Based on this change, WEB API introduced an ETag into the response from the OData Service.

Before, without `TimeStamp`:

```
{
"@odata.context":"http://localhost:50378/$metadata#Customers/$entity",
"Id":"c16883eb-3f4b-3515-9151-caa1c9e5bfc8",
"Name":"TestSeed"
}
```

Afer, with `TimeStamp`:

```
{
"@odata.context":"http://localhost:50378/$metadata#Customers/$entity",
"@odata.etag":"W/\"YmluYXJ5J0FBQUFBQUFBQjlrPSc=\"",
"Id":"c16883eb-3f4b-3515-9151-caa1c9e5bfc8",
"Name":"TestSeed",
"Version":"AAAAAAAAB9k="
}
```

## Question

Since WEB API introduced the Etag field in the response, 
**How do I hide the `Version` Property from the response?**

On the client side, everything is managed via the `ETag`.
It is only on the server, in the Data Access Layer, where the `Version` property is used.

The rationale behind hiding the `Version` property is to expose external users of our OData Service to Properties which is used for business purposes only.

**Am I missing something basic here**

Comment: The ETag identifies a resource, but the same resource may exist in different versions, so you need both, don't you?

Comment: My understanding is that the ETag contents are derived from the `Version` property, at least from Entity Framework to WEB API. The `Version` property here is a TimeStamp datatype which is updated by SQL each time data in a specific record change. Users only read the property.

Comment: Using [Decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/) I managed to decode the `ETag` and got the correct `Version` value. Encoding and Decoding is based on Base64

Answer (score -2):

if you do not need Version field just put the annotation in other field

```
public class Customer
{  
    [TimeStamp]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No, it's a bad idea to just mark some other property as timestamp/version. And `Id` is _the last property_ you'd want to use as timestamp, because it's immutable.